# PHP to Objective-C

Tags: php, objective-c, port

I have a PHP script that takes an HTML URL as input and provides text based on the returned HTML as output. What are my options for using this script within an iOS app.

1. Convert the PHP Script to Objective-C
2. Host the PHP script on a server and call the PHP script using the HTML URL as input.

Are there any other options I've missed? I'm assuming its a little bit too much to ask to have a Web server running within the app :)

I would prefer to do (1) via eLance/oDesk/RentACoder etc - is there a recommended site/company that would do this?

Thanks

Comment: While theoretically you *could* make a php interpreter run in-app, Apple will not allow it.

Comment: Is the second option allowed by App Policy?

Comment: Second option is what every single networked app on the app store does...

Answer (score 0):

This is *not* a way to run php code on your actual device, but an alternative option could be using the [Ip-Faces](http://www.sourcecodester.com/Tutorials/php/creating-iphone-application-php-using-ipfaces-framework.html) framework.

(this is mostly a candy-coated version of option 2)

Ip-Faces runs the php code on a server, but uses a native client app to render a UI, and handle client-side call events